# Checking for Alphabets in a String in java

Tags: java

I have a string "BC+D*E-". I want to check each character of the string whether it is an alphabet or not. I tried using isLetter() but it does consider even the = , * and - as alphabets.Can you please help me in this.Thanks in advance

Comment: And you've tried ... what? (post a snippet)

Comment: You can provide a new version of your own. Write a method, call isLetter from there. If it returns true, exit from the method. If it doesn't, check whether it's `=`, `*` or `-` and return true. If not, return false. The last three are not letters by the way :-) .

Comment: I assume you mean the English alphabet? What do you want to do with `=` and `+`?

Comment: Check the letter one by one instead of the whole string at once

Comment: `isLetter(char)` works. For me it says `*` or `-` or `=` is not a character.

Comment: `isLetter()` should _not_ consider '+' or '*' or '-' as letters (I'm assuming you are using `Character.isLetter()` method).

Comment: @all who are posting answers. Shouldn't we just let the OP either try it or atleast post some faulty code, before we go ahead and give the fully baked code?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for all ur help!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
    String s = "BC+D*E-=";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char charAt2 = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(charAt2)) {
            System.out.println(charAt2 + "is a alphabet");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Wrapper class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) [Character#isLetter(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) method

```
Character.isLetter(char c);
```

and check each letter one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet may help you.

```
 String startingfrom = "BC+D*E-".toUpperCase();
        char chararray[] = startingfrom.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++) {
                            int value = (int)chararray[i];
                            if((value >= 65 && value <= 90) || (value >= 97 && value <= 122))
                                System.out.println(chararray[i]+ " is an alphabate");
                            else 
                                System.out.println(chararray[i]+ " is not an alphabate");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the String into an array and iterate over it.

```
String word = "BC+D*E-"
for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
    if(!(Character.isLetter(c)) {
        System.out.println("Not a character!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII value of English letters. e.g.

```
for (char c : "BC+D*E-".toCharArray())
{
  int value = (int) c;
  if ((value >= 65 && value <= 90) || (value >= 97 && value <= 122))
  {
    System.out.println("letter");
  }
}
```

You can find ASCII table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringEx =  "BC+D*E-";
for (char string : stringEx.toCharArray()) {
    if ( ( (char)string > 64 ) && ((char)string < 91) )
        System.out.println("It is character");
    if ( ( (char)string > 96 ) && ((char)string < 123) )
    System.out.println("It is character");
}
```

You can use this code. This may also helpful to you.