# How to not count special character and vowels occurences in string length using user input

Tags: java, string-length

I just got into my 2nd programming subject but my prof just throws stuff at us that he didn't teach so I'm guessing that I need help from people because searching the internet's help ain't enough

So the output that I'm looking for is like this

```
Enter word : #$nsaei!
result = 2
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562265/checking-for-alphabets-in-a-string-in-java). It should be a simple adjustment to get what you're looking for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please edit your question so as to give more details about your situation and the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), converting the `String` input into a char array using [toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) and checking each char using [isLetterOrDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)) and checking if the character is not in `"AEIOUaeiou"` using [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and therefore not a vowel:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a word:");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    int consonantOrDigits = 0;
    for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
      if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) == -1)
        consonantOrDigits++;
    }

    System.out.println(consonantOrDigits);
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EvTT/5)

Comment: Wow thanks man I'm gonna study this later 
But what if we don't count the vowels as well(because this might help me in the future)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
System.out.println("Enter word: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.nextLine();

int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)).matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9&&[^aeuio]]*$")) {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println("result: " + count);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Enter word: 
#$nsaei!
result: 5`

Comment: @ScaryWombat It seems that the question was edited. The way I understood the question was to count everything except for the special symbols. But it turns out that vowels have to be considered as well. I will edit the answer. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: let me know when you have edited and I can remove the downvote.  (I know this is not your fault, but as it stands it is an incorrect answer).

Comment: @ScaryWombat I edited the answer. It should work now.