# how to count the number of alphabet in a pdf file in java

Tags: java, count, pdfbox

In this program, I need to count the number of all alphabets (a-z) and the code below is only able to count the number of "u". So if I want to count 26 of it, do I need to write 26 if statement in the for loop?

the output should be:
a:389
b:777
c:909
..
..

Please give me other solution

```
            String[] words = sourceCode.split(" ");
            amountOfWords = amountOfWords + words.length;
            for (String word : words) {
                amountOfChars = amountOfChars + word.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    if (word.charAt(i) == 'u' || word.charAt(i) == 'U') {
                        u++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please look at the word count questions here on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8 It's basically the same, just do it for the characters, i.e. `flatMap` each word to the chars in an additional step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for Alphabets in a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562265/checking-for-alphabets-in-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I am using library : **fontbox-2.0.12** and **pdfbox-2.0.12** and **commons-logging-1.2**

```
        try {
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("E:\\project-test\\scloud\\test\\src\\main\\resources\\Shadip_Banik.pdf"));
            String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);

            sourceCode = text.replace("-", "").replace(".", "");


            String[] words = sourceCode.split(" ");

            amountOfWords = amountOfWords + words.length;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (String word : words) {
                amountOfChars = amountOfChars + word.length();

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
                //System.out.println("MatchesCount "+matcher.group());
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    builder.append(matcher.group());

                }
            }
            String allData = builder.toString();
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
            int total = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<allAlphabate.length();i++)
            {
                int alphabateCount = 0;
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Character.toString(allAlphabate.charAt(i)));
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(allData);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    alphabateCount++;
                }
                total+=alphabateCount;
                System.out.println(allAlphabate.charAt(i) +" : "+alphabateCount);
            }
            if(total == builder.toString().length())
            {
                System.out.println("Yes   -------------------------------------------------");
            }
            System.out.println("Amount of Chars is " + amountOfChars);
            System.out.println("Amount of Words is " + (amountOfWords + 1));
            System.out.println("Average Word Length is " + (amountOfChars / amountOfWords));
        } catch (Exception ert) {

        }
```

But If you want to calculate uppercase and lowercase together use this code

```
     for (String word : words) {
                    amountOfChars = amountOfChars + word.length();

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word.toLowerCase());
                    //System.out.println("MatchesCount "+matcher.group());
                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        builder.append(matcher.group());

                    }
                }
                String allData = builder.toString();
                int total = 0;
                for (int i=0;i<allAlphabate.length();i++)
                {
                    int alphabateCount = 0;
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Character.toString(allAlphabate.charAt(i)));
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(allData.toLowerCase());
                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        alphabateCount++;
                    }
                    total+=alphabateCount;
                    System.out.println(allAlphabate.charAt(i) +" : "+alphabateCount);
                }
                if(total == builder.toString().length())
                {
                    System.out.println("Yes   -------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: the output is weird, it calculates the word occur how many times, not alphabet(a-z)

Comment: Check now. Probably it will that you desire

Comment: yaya, it looks what I want now, but these codes didn't count uppercase and lowercase together, right?

Comment: its calculate uppercase and lowercase toghether. you can do it some change on this code

Comment: change this to String allAlphabate = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; and then remove tolowercase function in sevaral places

Comment: Do you want to separate lowercase and uppercase separately.?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String str = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);    
int len = str.length();
Map<Character, Integer> numOfChars = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(Math.min(len, 26));

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)//pre increment
{
    char alphabet = str.charAt(i);    
    if (!numOfChars.containsKey(alphabet ))
    {
        numOfChars.put(alphabet , 1);
    }
    else
    {
        numOfChars.put(alphabet , numOfChars.get(alphabet ) + 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(numOfChars);
```

[Source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44187/156739)

Comment: these code basically print not only alphabet, it print symbol also like "=9, !=2

Comment: @Choy it is giving output like this `{a=3, s=1, d=1, w=1, h=1, i=2, m=1, n=4}` what else do you want?